# Matching substring in another string

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists that contain strings. The first list contains a list of files and directories:

```
list1 = ['path/to/my/files',
         'path/to/more/of/my/files',
         'path/to/my/dirs',
         'path/to/more/of/mydirs']
```

The second list contains dirs that I want to check against `list1` for existence.

```
list2 = ['path/to/my',
         'random/path/to/somewhere',
         'path/does/not/matter',
         'hey/path/is/here']
```

The only results I want is `path/to/my/*`, but when I use `str.find()` it is returning any string that contains `path` or `to` or `my` regardless of where it occurs in the string.

So instead of just getting:

```
path/to/my/files
path/to/my/dirs
```

I get everything in `list1`

My code is like so:

```
for dir in list2:
   for path in list1:
      if path.find(dir):
         print(path)
```

Comment: When you write "list", do you mean a file or a python `list`? There must be something missing from the code you posted here.

Comment: @jDo it is a python list

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find, you could also just use `if dir in path`, really find is used iif you want the index, you don't you just want to see if it matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* non-zero numbers are Truthy.  When your string is not found, `.find()` returns `-1` which is still `True`.  You need to make sure the result is not `-1`:

```
for dir in list2:
    for path in list1:
        if path.find(dir) != -1:
            print(path)
```

As @PadraicCunningham mentioned in a comment, that isn't the easiest way.  Just use the `in` operator:

```
for dir in list2:
    for path in list1:
        if dir in path:
            print(path)
```

Comment: I've tried this and it does not work.  I don't get any results and there are definitely matches.

Comment: @free_mind, this logic is correct based on your problem description, if it is not working then your description is incorrect not the solution.

Comment: @free_mind "there are definitely matches" How do you know? Have you printed all the paths? How do those look like, exactly? There may be some subtle problems not covered by your examples.

Comment: You guys were right, there was another issue that I resolved and then the code above worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think you what you need is `str.startswith()`

Comment: I'm new to python, is there a `str.startswith()`?

Comment: [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)